# Cleaning T-SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm new to T-SQL and trying to do some cleanup on some data imported from Excel into SQL Server.

I have made a batch import that imports the raw data to a staging table and now I want to clean it up.

I have the following tables

- `tblRawInput` (my stageing table):

  ```
  Name, Name2, Name3, Phonenumber, Group
  ```
- `tblPeople`:

  ```
  PersonID (IDENTITY), Name, Phonenumber, GroupID
  ```
- `tblGroups`:

  ```
  GroupID (IDENTITY), Groupname
  ```
- `tblAltNames`:

  ```
  NameID (IDENTITY), Name, PersonID
  ```

The query should be able to split the data into the other tables, but not create a group if it already exists.

I am at a loss. Could anyone give me a pointer in the right direction.

When I do a `SELECT INTO` it creates multiple copies of the groups.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do here. I think you need to have a number of insert statements but it is hard to know for sure.

Comment: You never use select into for insrts to production tables that already exist. It is only used for temp tables and tables that don't aready exist (which shoudl not be happening on prod if you havea decent database design)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` clause to insert only new groups:

```
insert  into Groups
        (GroupName)
select  distinct Group
from    tblRawInput ri
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Groups
        where   g.GroupName = ri.Group
        )
```

After this, you can insert into `tblPeople` like;

```
insert  tblPeople
        (Name, GroupID)
select  ri.Name
,       g.GroupID
from    tblRawInput ri
-- Look up GroupID in the Groups table
join    Groups g
on      g.GroupName = ri.Group
```

You can do the alternate names along the same lines.

Comment: Probably need a distinct as well. And you need to see if they are putting groups ina comma delimited list, you may need to separate them out.

Comment: The first statement adds the duplicates as before. I was thinking about grouping the Groups upon insert into the Groups table but then there would be no refference!?

Comment: Right, you should use `distinct` like HLGEM suggests, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

First in this case order matters. Insert to groups first.

```
insert  into tblGroups
        (GroupName)
select  Group
from    tblRawInput ri
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    tblGroups g
        where   g.GroupName = ri.Group
        )
```

Then insert to the people table

```
Insert into tblPeople(Name, Phonenumber, GroupID)
Select Name, Phonenumber, GroupID 
from tblRawInput ri
join tblGroups g
   on g.groupName = ri.group
where   not exists
            (
            select  *
            from    tblPeople p
            where   p.Name = ri.Name
            and p.Phonenumber = ri.Phonenumber
            and p.groupId = g.groupid
            )
```

Then get the alt name

```
Insert into tblAltNames (Name, Personid)
Select Distinct Name2, PersonID 
from tblRawInput ri
join tblPerson p
   on  p.Name = ri.Name
where   not exists
            (
            select  *
            from    tblAltNames p
            where   p.Name = ri.Name2
             )
```

Of course all of this should be wrapped in a transaction and a try catch block with a rollback of everything is one of the inserts fails.

Possibly the second query shoudl use the output clause to get teh personids inserted instead of the join. You don't really have anything good to join on here because names are not unique.